# Porque la fecha vuelve como undefined cuando obtengo los datos de la API?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, react-hooks

Cuando hago el POST Request todos los datos se envían bien pero luego cuando quiero traer los datos en el campo de la fecha `releaseData` este tiene como valor `undefined`.
App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

import AddMovie from './components/AddMovie';
import MoviesList from './components/MoviesList';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // Factorizar estas 2 funciones:
  const fetchMoviesHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://fir-movie-app-2761f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/movies.json'
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong ' + response.status);
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      const loadedMovies = [];

      for (const key in data) {
        loadedMovies.push({
          id: key,
          title: data[key].title,
          openingText: data[key].openingText,
          releaseData: data[key].releaseData,
        });
      }
      console.log(loadedMovies);
      setMovies(loadedMovies);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMoviesHandler();
  }, [fetchMoviesHandler]);

  const addMovieHandler = async movie => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://fir-movie-app-2761f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/movies.json',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(movie),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong ' + response.status);
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  let content = <p>Movie Not Found.</p>;

  if (movies.length > 0) {
    content = <MoviesList movies={movies} />;
  }
  if (error) {
    content = <p>{error}</p>;
  }
  if (isLoading) {
    content = <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <section>
        <AddMovie onAddMovie={addMovieHandler} />
      </section>
      <section>
        <button onClick={fetchMoviesHandler}>Fetch Movies</button>
      </section>
      <section>{content}</section>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Escribiste mal la propiedad "releaseData", es releaseDate

```
for (const key in data) {
  loadedMovies.push({
    id: key,
    title: data[key].title,
    openingText: data[key].openingText,
    releaseData: data[key].releaseDate,
  });
}
```

Comment: Como sabías ..?

Comment: Fácil, solo agregue un log en tu iteración, donde me di cuenta que al propiedad que accedes estaba mal escrita